# Requiring unknown module "ReactPerf" while integrating React Native with existing Android app

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to integrate the latest React Native build and I'm running into errors. Here is my project setup:

In the app's build.gradle, I import react-native 0.24.1:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.24.1'
}
```

The project's build.gradle points to React Native which is in a Git submodule:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$projectDir/../MyGitSubmodule/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

I have otherwise integrated as described in the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html#content) and upgraded RN in the git submodule as described in the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html). I've uploaded my stack trace to this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/G7ycGSA7). To summarize the stack trace as the formatting is hard to read, these are the highlights:

- Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager -- this applies for a ton of Native classes. Maybe all of them.
- Error: Requiring unknown module "ReactPerf". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager or running "npm install"
- Got JS Exception: Error: Requiring module "23" which threw an exception
- Got JS Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: __fbBatchedBridge
- In addition, the emulator shows the red screen of death with the following message -- "Error: Requiring module "8" which threw an exception"

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: I fixed it by adding `apply from: "../MyGitSubmodule/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` to the top of my app's build.gradle. I didn't want to add it as an answer, because I can't explain exactly what it does. I know there was some packaging issues with the JavaScript. The react.gradle appears to be creating a bundle, but I guess that is not the case, since I am able to Reload JS in the emulator. I would appreciate a more definitive answer from someone better informed.

Comment: I fixed it by adding a dependency on React. From a certain version of react native it needs React itself.

Comment: You added the dependency in npm? Or gradle as well? I noticed that I needed to add React as a dependency in node also, but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's complaining that module `ReactPerf` is required but it doesn't exist.

FYI, `ReactPerf` module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-perf.

Logically, we simply need to tell react-native to install this thing.

The tricky part is that if we do that by doing:

`npm install react-addons-perf`, then we're installing it "outside" of the `react-native` dependency. And consequently, it will complain that `react-addons-perf` requires `react` package as well.

Solution is that we need to declare this dependency "inside" react-native package. In other words:

Open `node_modules/react-native/package.json`. You will find

```
...
"dependencies": {
"absolute-path": "^0.0.0",
"art": "^0.10.0",
"babel-core": "~6.4.5",
"babel-plugin-external-helpers": "~6.4.0",
...
"react": "^0.14.5"
...
}
```

So, what we need to do is just add `react-addons-perf` to those.

```
...
"dependencies": {
"absolute-path": "^0.0.0",
"art": "^0.10.0",
"babel-core": "~6.4.5",
"babel-plugin-external-helpers": "~6.4.0",
...
"react": "^0.14.5",
"react-addons-perf": "^0.14.5", // ADD THIS LINE FOR ReactPerf module
...
}
```

Then, `npm install`.

From my experience, the rest of the error such as `Requiring module "8"` will be gone too.

It worked for me and, hopefully, it works for you too.

Comment: is there an `$   rnpm link` missing in there too, after the npm install?